# Is there a passive for the sentence "Be quiet."?

Tags: verbs, passive-voice

How to say "Be quiet.", which is a command, in passive voice?

Comment: Is there a stylistic need for a this or is it just out of curiosity?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Only transitive verbs can form passive constructions and *be* is not a transitive verb.

Answer (score 12):

*Quiet* is a predicate adjective, and almost all predicate adjectives are intransitive. Passive can only apply to a transitive predicate.

*Be* is an auxiliary verb, required to hold the tense for the predicate adjective; no auxiliary verb ever governs Passive. Indeed, the Passive construction uses *be* itself.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like "Silence would be appreciated." captures the meaning without being a command.

Answer (score 1):

"Let yourself be quieted" is a command in passive voice. While grammatically correct, it is also extremely convoluted, and sounds awkward.

"Let yourself be quietened" would be another British English variant, but no less awkward.

Comment: 'Quieten'? This is less than rare, it is unheard of in American English.

Comment: @Mitch I've updated the answer to offer the American version, and more importantly to offer a command that actually uses the passive voice.

Comment: @Mitch It's on the rise ... Ngrams: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quieten&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquieten%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Greybeard Yes and seems to be acceptable by some. But always compare rises against the common alternatives, ['quieten' almost flat lines next to 'quiet' (as a verb)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quieten%2Cquiet_VERB&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3). It still sounds like a malapropism to me.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

> The unruly class ***was quieted down by the teacher*** sharply whacking her yardstick on her desk.

Answer (score -1):

Be quiet : according to my point of view,this sentence will need  verb to request to be into passive otherwise it won't change

Comment: Please support your claim with references, examples, an explanation, etc. See [*How to reference material written by others*](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) and [*How do I write a good answer?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).