# Passive voice of "Stay"

Tags: passive-voice

What would be the passive voice of "passengers stay in a hotel".

The whole sentence would be "passengers can be forwarded to their destination in a new flight, or (be kept) in a hotel". "Kept" is not a word I want to use for humans :)

Comment: How about *passengers can be forwarded to their destination in a new flight, or stay in a hotel*? There is no need for a passive verb here. That is probably also the reason why no passive exists anyway. Unless you mean *put up in a hotel*, which means more than simply staying, and hence it is a different verb.

Comment: Related: [Is there a passive for the sentence “Be quiet”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/85006/) (and probably a dozen others, but that one got posted just a couple hours ago). The answer is [always the same](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/85006/is-there-a-passive-for-the-sentence-be-quiet/85008#85008).

Comment: As a matter of good style, there is no need to use a second passive verb in this sentence.  You can simply use 'stay', or, for better sentence rhythm (not quite sure on your meaning) 'choose to stay.'  Also, it should be "on" a new flight.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can only form a passive out of a transitive verb.  *To stay* when used transitively does not mean the same thing as used intransitively.

The word you might be looking for is *lodged*.  People can be lodged in or at a hotel.

Comment: +1 for the first sentence, but I think in practice brochures and the like would probably say *or [passengers can] be **accommodated** in a hotel*.

Comment: "Lodge" is transitive only when it means "wedge" or something similar, hm? You can lodge a shim in a gap, but you can't lodge a hotel.

Comment: @Tony But you do hear people saying that they lodged *at* a hotel. Lots of hits for that one.

Comment: @tchrist Yeah, but "at a hotel" answers _where_, not _what_. Likewise, you can say "I read a book" or "I read at a hotel". The first can be made passive (a book was read by me), but the second cannot (*at a hotel was read by me), because it's not a transitive formulation.

Answer (score 11):

Besides tchrist's suggestion of *lodged*, you could also say

> Passengers can be sent to their destination on a different flight or be *housed* at a hotel.

(In this instance, [house](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/house) has the definition of: to give shelter to; harbor; lodge

Or you could say:

> Passengers can be sent to their destination on a different flight *or be put up in a hotel*.

Or you could say:

> Passengers can be sent to their destination on a different flight or can be provided with a hotel room.

Answer (score 1):

The term *[checked-in](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/check-in) to a hotel* is often used, especially when the airline or agency is making the arrangements.

Answer (score -2):

I think using stay is already the best solution. The fundamental purpose of using language is to express our opinion in a clear and neat way rather than to using impressive expression to attract the attention

Comment: The original poster is asking for a solution in passive voice.

Comment: But shall we at first identify the fundamental purpose of finding the passive voice of stay before answering that?

Comment: If you want to stress that the passive voice is unnecessary, please state so in your answer along with an explanation. A comparison of _passengers can stay in a hotel_ and _passengers can be accommodated in a hotel_ (within the context of the OP's sentence) will also be interesting.

Answer (score -2):

The literal passive version would be "a hotel can be stayed in by passengers" or just "a hotel can be stayed in".

Both are clunky--and also cold. They make it sound like you want no part in the action and couldn't care less what the passengers do. If you're asking for a better solution, I think some have already been given.